# Which editor/plugin to use if I want control over the html tags surrounding the text inside a wysiwyg textarea?

Tags: html, text-editor

For instance, I want to be able to do something like:

```
<p style="text-indent: 0">This is the first paragraph</p>
<p style="text-indent: 2.4em">This is the first paragraph</p>
<p style="text-indent: 2.4em">This is the first paragraph</p>
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps look into [TinyMCE](http://www.tinymce.com/).

Or if you'd rather go the markdown route, try [Hallo](http://hallojs.org/demo/markdown/)